# elasticsearch metricbeats docker install error

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, metricbeat

Hello everyone I'm new in elk stack.
I'm trying to run elk in docker with metricbeats. But unfortunately I have a problem with metricbeat setup.

```
docker run \
docker.elastic.co/beats/metricbeat:7.9.1 \
setup -E setup.kibana.host=ELK-IP-Address:5601 \
-E output.elasticsearch.hosts=["ELK-IP-Address:9200"] \
-E output.elasticsearch.username=elastic \
-E output.elasticsearch.password=changeme
```

When I run that code in my terminal I have that error.

```
zsh: no matches found: output.elasticsearch.hosts=[elasticsearch:9200]
```

Please help me:(

Answer (score 2):

Add a backslash `\` behind each of the square brackets, i.e. `output.elasticsearch.hosts=\[elasticsearch:9200\]`